# removed the app by google play How do I solve it

Tags: react-native, google-play, google-play-console

I have made an app for 3 years in Iran and it's about that removed by google play I put the error pictured below [image] when I publish a new version after some hours rejected the app also gives an update rejected in issue details [image] and I don't know how to solve the problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

Login to your play console

**Go to >> App content >> App Access**

[image]

**Now, if your app requires login/signin**

Select "All or some functionality in my app is restricted" and add any testing credentials

**If you app doesn't require Login/Signin**

Select "All functionality in my app is available without any access restrictions" and Save.

Now, Head Towards **Publishing Overview** section and publish your changes.

Comment: hi it didn't work

Comment: @farshid.chegini What error are you facing now? If it is same, did you added testing credentials in "+Add Instructions" section in App access page

Comment: I have just one way that is mobile number and sms and I can't send sms to other countries except my country